# How do I calculate population within radius on Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, vector, buffer, population, radius

I'm trying to calculate the population within a specific radius within a specific country using Google Earth Engine. My plan is to use reduceToVectors to convert the population values into a featureCollection to then use a buffer. The final goal is to be able to use Inspector to click on a specific pixel and see the population within x km of the pixel as a value.

My code is below:

```js
// Load country boundaries
var countryBoundaries = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level0");

// Filter country boundaries for specific country
var selectedCountry = countryBoundaries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME','Afghanistan'))

// Load population dataset
var popDataset = ee.ImageCollection("CIESIN/GPWv411/GPW_UNWPP-Adjusted_Population_Count")

// Retrieve the most recent population image
var recentPop = popDataset.limit(1, 'system:time_start', false).first();

// Round population values to integers
var popCount = recentPop.select('unwpp-adjusted_population_count').round();

// Clip population dataset to just the selected country, retain integer values
var clipped = popCount.clip(selectedCountry).toInt()

// Population vis params
var popVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 200,
  palette: ['#B1F9E8','#8EE1D3','#6AC9BE','#47B0AA','#239895','#008080']
}

// Convert the clipped dataset to a feature collection
var vector = clipped.reduceToVectors(null, selectedCountry, 5100)

print(vector)

// Convert the feature collection to a feature to use a buffer
var feature = ee.Feature(vector)

// Create a buffer with a 50 km radius per point
var buffer = feature.buffer(50000)

// Add the population layer to the map
Map.addLayer(clipped, popVis, '2020 Population')

// Add the buffer layer to the map
Map.addLayer(buffer, popVis, 'buffered population')
```

My main issue is that I can't display the "buffered population" on the map because I get the following error: "Layer error: Feature.buffer: Unable to use a collection in an algorithm that requires a feature or image. This may happen when trying to use a collection of collections where a collection of features is expected; use flatten, or map a function to convert inner collections to features. Use clipToCollection (instead of clip) to clip an image to a collection."

Is there a way to make it so that when I click on a specific pixel, it shows the total population within the buffer radius?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question.  Bullet lists of questions will generate closure votes for lack of *focus*. Please pick the one question you want to ask and [Edit] the Question to focus on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially a duplicate of your previous question, with the addition of handling clicks on the map? The following will show the total population within a radius of 200m of where you clicked. Adjust the radius as you want.

```
Map.style().set('cursor', 'crosshair')
Map.onClick(printPopulation)
Map.setOptions('HYBRID')

var population = ee.ImageCollection("CIESIN/GPWv411/GPW_UNWPP-Adjusted_Population_Count")
  .limit(1, 'system:time_start', false)
  .mosaic()
  .select(['unwpp-adjusted_population_count'], ['population']).round()

var populationSum = population.reduceNeighborhood({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
  kernel: ee.Kernel.circle(200, 'meters'),
  inputWeight: 'mask'
})

Map.addLayer(population, {min: 0, max: 300, palette: '#042333, #2c3395, #744992, #b15f82, #eb7958, #fbb43d, #e8fa5b'}, 'population', false)
Map.addLayer(populationSum, {min: 0, max: 5000, palette: '#042333, #2c3395, #744992, #b15f82, #eb7958, #fbb43d, #e8fa5b'}, 'populationSum', false)

function printPopulation(latLon) {
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point([latLon.lon, latLon.lat])
  var populationAroundPoint = populationSum.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first(), 
    geometry: point, 
    scale: 100, 
  }).getNumber('population_sum')
  
  print(populationAroundPoint)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/dd55de200c0a57244059db8e6cf06f34